# Change the file encoding to UTF-8 without knowing input encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, talend

Given a file which can either be encoded using UTF-8 or using another encoding (likely latin1), how can I change its encoding to have an output encoded using UTF-8 ?

I first tried using the tChangeFileEncoding component without specifying the input encoding. This did not work because not specifying the input encoding makes it default to the locale.

I then tried to specify the input encoding to ISO8859-1 (latin1).
This did not work either since the files that were originally in UTF-8 were read in the wrong encoding, introducing weird characters.

I cannot use shell commands such as `iconv` or `recode` and must do everything in TOS.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are expecting this to work if you don't know how the file was encoded? Even if you could use iconv/recode you'd still need to know how the file was encoded